# Updating the UI automaticly

Tags: java, multithreading, android

I'm working on a Android program that gets his sensor data from a seperate class ( the data i print out in the onSensorChange method and looks fine). No i want to update my UI with the data i have got. The UI consits of some textviews in a activity (main activity) in the onCreate method i initialize the sensor class that gets the sensor data.

I tried to use the thread an UIthread in the onCreate method of the activity but the textviews do not update. Does anybody have a sugestion?

The onCreate tlooks like this ( in the prints of the onSensorChange i get the correct data):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


CompassHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CompassValue);
AccelValueZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AccelValueZ);
AccelValueY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AccelValueY);
AccelValueX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AccelValueX);
GyroValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GyroValue);

SensorM = new SensorModule(getApplicationContext()); //<<---Created instance of SensorModule

new Thread(new Runnable(){
    //@Override
        public void run(){

            CompassHeading.setText("Heading: " + Float.toString(SensorM.AccelerationResult[0]) + " degrees");

            AccelValueZ.setText(Float.toString(Math.round(SensorM.AccelerationResult[2])));
            AccelValueY.setText(Float.toString(Math.round(SensorM.AccelerationResult[1])));
            AccelValueX.setText(Float.toString(Math.round(SensorM.AccelerationResult[0]))); 

            GyroValue.setText("Orientation X (Roll) :"+ Float.toString(Math.round(SensorM.AccelerationData[2])) +"\n"+  
                              "Orientation Y (Pitch) :"+ Float.toString(Math.round(SensorM.AccelerationData[1])) +"\n"+  
                              "Orientation Z (Yaw) :"+ Float.toString(Math.round(SensorM.AccelerationData[0])));                
        }
    });
```

And the onSensorChange of the SensorModule class:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
System.out.println("In onSensorChanged");

System.out.println("=====================");
// Get a local copy of the sensor values
System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, AccelerationData, 0, event.values.length);    

AccelerationData[0] = AccelerationData[0] / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
AccelerationData[1] = AccelerationData[1] / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
AccelerationData[2] = AccelerationData[2] / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;

// Get result
AccelerationResult = GetAcceleration(AccelerationData); 

    System.out.println("Orientation X (Roll) :"+ Float.toString(Math.round(AccelerationData[2])) +"\n"+  
                   "Orientation Y (Pitch) :"+ Float.toString(Math.round(AccelerationData[1])) +"\n"+  
                   "Orientation Z (Yaw) :"+ Float.toString(Math.round(AccelerationData[0])));

    System.out.println("Acceleration X :"+ Float.toString(Math.round(AccelerationResult[2])) +"\n"+  
                   "Acceleration Y :"+ Float.toString(Math.round(AccelerationResult[1])) +"\n"+  
                   "Acceleration Z :"+ Float.toString(Math.round(AccelerationResult[0])));
}
```

## Update

Thank you all for your suggestions! I have modefied the main activity code. Here i make a thread, runnable object and a handler. Now i get so data but the problem is that i only get sometimes new data and not all fields are updated. Do i have implemented the thread and handler correctly? I want to get an update as fast as possible with all the data of the current fields. Does anybody see a problem in the code below? All sugestions are welcome!

Below is the main activity code:

```
    package com.example.sensormodule;

import com.example.SensorModuleClass.SensorModule;
import com.example.sensormodule.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    TextView CompassHeading;
    TextView AccelValueZ;
    TextView AccelValueY;
    TextView AccelValueX;
    TextView GyroValue;
    String value;   

    SensorModule SensorM;

    // Need handler for callbacks to the UI thread
    final Handler UpdateUIHandler = new Handler();

    // Create runnable for posting
    final Runnable UpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            UpdateResultToUI();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        CompassHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CompassValue);
        AccelValueZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AccelValueZ);
        AccelValueY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AccelValueY);
        AccelValueX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AccelValueX);
        GyroValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GyroValue);

        SensorM = new SensorModule(getApplicationContext());

            StartUpdateToUI();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    protected void StartUpdateToUI() {

        // Fire off a thread to do some work that we shouldn't do directly in the UI thread
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                while(true){
                //Keep updating the UI
                    UpdateUIHandler.post(UpdateResults);
                }
            }
        };
            t.start();
    }


    private void UpdateResultToUI() {

        CompassHeading.setText("Heading: " + Float.toString(SensorM.AccelerationResult[0]) + " degrees");

        AccelValueZ.setText(Float.toString(Math.round(SensorM.AccelerationResult[2])));
        AccelValueY.setText(Float.toString(Math.round(SensorM.AccelerationResult[1])));
        AccelValueX.setText(Float.toString(Math.round(SensorM.AccelerationResult[0]))); 

        GyroValue.setText("Orientation X (Roll) :"+ Float.toString(Math.round(SensorM.AccelerationData[2])) +"\n"+  
                          "Orientation Y (Pitch) :"+ Float.toString(Math.round(SensorM.AccelerationData[1])) +"\n"+  
                          "Orientation Z (Yaw) :"+ Float.toString(Math.round(SensorM.AccelerationData[0])));   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of problems here:

1) You are creating a new `Thread`, but you are not calling its `start()`, so the `Thread` is never ran.

2) If you do call the `start()` you will get an `Exception` saying you are trying to modify the UI `Thread` from a background `Thread`.

If you need to update the UI after a some background `Thread` finishes you should use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Comment: @Emmanuel: Thank you for your answer! i have followed your sugerstions and used a handler! But the problem that i have now is that i only get "Sometimes data" Do you mind to have a look? i have updated my code under update

Comment: I solved it by using a timer and the runonuithreat to update ui as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

As emmanual suggested the best threading operations are done with asyntask. but if you want to change the ui in a thread you can use parentActivity.runonuithread(runnable){change} this is not the best way but it works or use it with handler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have implemented a handler and a thread but no i only get "some times" data. I have updated my code under update. Do you mind the have a look?